Hartshorne Chapter II Proposition 2.6
My question arises from Hartshorne's textbook Algebraic Geometry Chapter II, proposition 2.6. There are already many questions regarding this proposition on MSE. In the proof, it is stated in the second paragraph that

Since any variety can be covered by open affine subvarieties(I, 4.3), it will be sufficient to show that if $V$ is affine, then $(t(V),\alpha_*(\mathcal{O}_V))$ is a scheme.

This is where I do not understand. I already know that open subsets of $V$ and $t(V)$ are in one-to-one correspondence by $V\backslash Y \leftrightarrow t(V)\backslash t(Y)$, with $Y$ any closed subset of $V$. Now assume $V$ is covered by the affine open subsets $U_i$. The proof shows, with abuse of notation, that each $t(U_i)$ is an affine scheme. We may denote $U_i$ to be $V\backslash Y_i$.
The problem is, how would this make the whole $t(V)$ a scheme? Indeed, $t(V)$ is a scheme once it is covered by open covers $t(V)\backslash t(Y_i)$, and each $t(V)\backslash t(Y_i)$ is isomorphic to some affine scheme. However, even as sets, $t(V)\backslash t(Y_i)$ may not equal to $t(V\backslash Y_i)$, in the sense that $V\backslash Y_i$ may not be a closed subset of $V$, even though it does correspond to $t(V)\backslash t(Y_i)$. For example, we may let $V\backslash Y_i=U_i$ be irreducible and not closed (This can be done by, for example, taking $V$ to be a projective space). Then $U_i\in t(U_i)$ while $U_i\notin t(V)\backslash t(Y_i)$. After all, what $t(V)\backslash t(Y_j)$ are the open affine coverings of $t(V)$ and why are they affine?
Besides, the book also says that with $t(V)$ indeed a scheme, there is a natural map
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{Var}(k)}(V,W)\to\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{Sch}(k)}(t(V),t(W))$$
I cannot give this natural map, mostly due to the problem above. This also makes me stuck when trying to prove Ex. 2.15. If this is not that trivial, hopefully one may give an explicit construction of the natural map.

I do not understand how you have gotten so confused. Here are the only two things you need to prove:

If $U\subset V$ is open, then $t(U)\subset t(V)$ is open.
If $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of $V$, then $\{t(U_i)\}_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of $t(V)$.

Proof of 1: Write $Z= V\setminus U$. Then we have injective maps $t(Z)\to t(V)$ and $t(U)\to t(V)$ which we will identify with their images. By the definition of the topology on $t(V)$, the set $t(Z)\subset t(V)$ is closed. We'll show that $t(U)=t(V)\setminus t(Z)$, which will establish that $t(U)$ is open. Let $S\subset V$ be an irreducible closed subset. Either $S$ intersects $U$ or $S$ is contained in $Z$ - in the first case, the irreducible closed subset $U\cap S \subset U$ is sent to $S$ under the map $t(U)\to t(V)$, so $S\in t(U)$; in the second, the irreducible subset $S$ is inside $t(Z)$ by definition. So in fact $t(V)=t(U)\cup t(Z)$ and $t(U)\cap t(Z)=\emptyset$ and we're done.
Proof of 2: Let $Y_i=V\setminus U_i$ be the corresponding closed subset for each $i\in I$. As the $U_i$ are an open cover, we have that $\bigcap_i Y_i = \emptyset$, and so $\bigcap_i t(Y_i) = t(\bigcap_i Y_i) = t(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, showing that in fact the $U_i$ cover $t(V)$ (we know they're open from our previous proof).
Therefore given an affine open covering of $V$, if we can prove that $(t(-),\alpha_*(\mathcal{O}_-))$ of an affine open is again an affine open, we may obtain an affine open covering of $t(V)$, showing that it is in fact a scheme.

The natural map $$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{Var}(k)}(V,W)\to\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{Sch}(k)}(t(V),t(W))$$ is obtained by applying the functor $t$ to the underlying map of topological spaces $f:V\to W$ and transporting the map of sheaves over in the only possible way, since $\alpha_V:V\to t(V)$ and $\alpha_W:W\to t(W)$ give bijections between the lattices of open sets of the two varieties.
